# laravel5.1 retrieve cookie data (returns null all the time)

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-5.1

After I set a cookie in Laravel I tried to retrieve it's content by using this code. It returns all the time null, but the cookie is set:

```
 public function postRegister(Request $request)
{

    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {

        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    $value =  \Request::cookie('affiliate_id');
    dd( $value );

    $user = $this->create($request->all());

    return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans('account.verify'));

}
```

[image: cookie is set]

As you can see, the value of cookie "affiliate_id" is not empty.

Comment: Post your complete controller method, So I can check that what can be the issue. for the time you try this `$value =  \Request::cookie('affiliate_id');`

Comment: I updated code above. Same result. Saying "null" all the time. This is so strange.

Comment: move your code on top of validator line and check this, you getting the value or not. `echo \Request::cookie('XSRF-TOKEN'); die();`

Comment: It works, I get the XSRF Token, but when I try to get the content of `affiliate_id`it returned a blank page (because it's null).

Comment: try to use `laravel_session` cookie, check it returns value or not ? and also add http with your website address eg `http://smp.local.dev`